# freshclam warning: "DNS record is older than 3 hours."

Tags: updates, dns, clamav

I recently ran the command:

```
sudo freshclam
```

And this was the output:

```
ClamAV update process started at Mon Sep 28 18:45:04 2015
WARNING: DNS record is older than 3 hours.
WARNING: Invalid DNS reply. Falling back to HTTP mode.
Reading CVD header (main.cvd): OK
main.cvd is up to date (version: 55, sigs: 2424225, f-level: 60, builder: neo)
Reading CVD header (daily.cvd): OK
Downloading daily-20941.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-20942.cdiff [100%]
Downloading daily-20943.cdiff [100%]
daily.cld updated (version: 20943, sigs: 1593145, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Reading CVD header (safebrowsing.cvd): OK
Empty script safebrowsing-43862.cdiff, need to download entire database
Downloading safebrowsing.cvd [100%]
safebrowsing.cvd updated (version: 43865, sigs: 2282876, f-level: 63, builder: google)
Reading CVD header (bytecode.cvd): OK (IMS)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 268, sigs: 47, f-level: 63, builder: anvilleg)
Database updated (6300293 signatures) from db.uk.clamav.net (IP: 172.110.204.67)
Clamd successfully notified about the update.
```

So what do all the warnings in there mean? And is there anything that I need to do about them or is this fully a server-side issue?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.16
```

**Package Information:**

```
clamav-freshclam:
  Installed: 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.98.7+dfsg-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.98.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a DNS problem and `freshclam` is just warning you about it...

(The clue to that is in the label `WARNING`)  **;-) :P**

As you didn't provide any DNS information, it's hard to pinpoint the exact source of the issue (I wouldn't even call it a problem), but probably you've got an ISP that doesn't refresh its DNS resolver very frequently.

2 options:

1. Change your DNS to a better maintained one manually (E.G. [here](http://public-dns.tk/) is a list, take the one with the lowest ping and the highest reliability)
2. Contact your ISP, complain bitterly, refer them [here](https://askubuntu.com/users/364819/paranoid-panda) telling them you've got a 173000 user blog and that you'll expose them as a *<s>shitty</s> not very reliable* ISP and *maybe* they'll do something about it so you and all of your ISP's users will benefit.